# How to omit specific controller or list of api starting path with "api/v2/internal/*" from Swagger documentation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

How to omit specific controller  or list of API starting the path with "api/v2/internal/*" from Swagger documentation

Comment: What language / framework do you use? Java + Springfox, .NET + Swashbuckle, something else? Please also post your controller code and configs.

Comment: Spring Boot + Springfox is being used